# Update query for a single column between two huge tables

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, bulkupdate

I have table with 58 million records with having 30 columns in which I want update one column by mapping with another table which is having 45 million records with two columns.

```
MERGE INTO /*+ PARALLEL(tbl_temp) */ tbl_temp tcm
USING (SELECT frn.id, frn.risk FROM temp_new frn ) a
ON (a.id = tcm.fi_id) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
SET tcm.risk_label=a.risk;
```

above is the query which I have tried but it is taking more than 12 hrs. I have tried with batch wise update also with batch size 10000 but same issue. Is there any other way to improve the performance of the query

Comment: Hints go after the first keyword (`merge`, `insert`, `select` etc).

Comment: Usually when you make `MERGE` but only with `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE` clause then a simple `UPDATE` would be sufficient. Do you have indexes on `ID` and `FI_ID`? Is table `TBL_TEMP` partitioned? If not, then PARALLEL hint does not makes much sense.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, Yes we have indexes on specified columns and the table is not partitioned.

Comment: I'm not sure indexes will be any help since temp_new has 45 million rows and you are joining all of them to your 58 million row target table. I would hope the execution plan shows full scans and a hash join. (If it's using indexes that might be the problem.)

Comment: You probably want to be carrying out an operation like this without transaction logging.. Blog post about massive DML ops without generating huge amounts of undo/redo (hopefully you're using a recent oracle): http://blog.dbi-services.com/can-we-disable-logging-for-dml/

Comment: Do many of the `tcm.risk_label` values already have the values that are in `temp_new.risk`? If so, perhaps you could cut down the amount of work needed by adding something like `where nvl(tcm.risk_label,chr(0)) <> nvl(a.risk,chr(0))`. However it still has to do the 45 million row hash join.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, yes I have some of tcm.risk_label values that are in temp_new.risk

Comment: @CaiusJard, I'm a recent oracle user only. So not having enough knowledge on how to handling bulk data. This also I got from the forums (stackoverflow, asktom, etc.,)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have enough free space use recreate your table - create new table with temp name and same structure, use insert as select from current table left joined to mapping table, using parallel and append hint. Rename current table, rename new table to actual name. Move all indexes/synonyms, grants/triggers and etc from old table to the new one. Test your application. If it's fine then you can drop the old one.

Comment: Could possibly empty and refill the old table when the new table is as required, saving on having to do some DDL for the periphery objects

Comment: If migration takes hours I doubt that this is good idea. It's easier to reapply ddls. There is another way - create new table as partitioned with 1 partition (system for example) and then use exchange partition to move data back to old table.